# Split variadic template params up to use as single template parameters for other classes

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I'm trying to figure out how to give arbitrary template parameters to a class, then have that class use each of those parameters to instantiate a bass class. Something along these lines:

```cpp
template<class T>
SingleParamClass;

template<class ... TYPE_LIST>
MultiParamClass : SingleParamClass<TYPE_LIST[0]>, SingleParamClass<TYPE_LIST[1]>... SingleParamClass<TYPE_LIST[N]>;
```

I've written it with indexing into the parameter pack just for demonstration purposes obviously.

I know how to unpack the type list, but not how to unpack it in a way that I can use it as above.

**Edit:**

As requested I'll expand on what I'm trying to do...

I want to make a subclass that constructs a series of pure virtual methods using the types in the variadic template params. These pure virtual methods are there for another component to call, and simultaneously forces the dev to implement those methods in the derived class.

In a world where C++ magically works the way I want, I'd do something like this:

```cpp
template<class ... TYPE_LIST>
MultiParamClass {

    virtual void func(TYPE_LIST[0] arg) = 0;
    virtual void func(TYPE_LIST[1] arg) = 0;
    ...
    virtual void func(TYPE_LIST[N] arg) = 0;

}
```

I don't know a way to do this, so I'm trying to find a way around it using subclasses, something like this:

```cpp
template<class T>
SingleParamClass {
    virtual void func(T arg) = 0;
}

template<class ... TYPE_LIST>
MultiParamClass : SingleParamClass<TYPE_LIST[0]>, SingleParamClass<TYPE_LIST[1]>... SingleParamClass<TYPE_LIST[N]>;
```

Comment: Please explain what is this template for, what it should do and if it has some special cases. Possible provide a code which uses this template as way to explain what you actually need.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Wcaxoad3s

Comment: There is a trick to popping the first element of a parameter pack off. IIRC Basically you pass it to a template that takes one element and another parameter pack, passing it the parameter pack you want to split. Through recursion you can eventually split off all the elements one by one. Assembling this idea to serve for what you want above is up to you

Comment: @Taekahn - I'd considered this approach, but I couldn't think of a way of using that approach that doesn't result in a heirachy of subclasses as long as the parameter pack itself, which is a much less ideal solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can expand the parameter pack like so:

```
template<class T>
struct SingleParamClass {};

template<class ... TYPE_LIST>
struct MultiParamClass : SingleParamClass<TYPE_LIST>... {};
```

Comment: That's perfect, thanks alot! I had no idea that syntax existed

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try something like this:

```
template<class T>
class SingleParamClass
{
public:
    virtual void func(T arg) = 0;
};

template<class... TYPE_LIST>
class MultiParamClass : public SingleParamClass<TYPE_LIST>...
{
};

class MyMultiParamClass : public MultiParamClass<int, double, string>
{
public:
    void func(int arg) override { ... }
    void func(double arg) override { ... }
    void func(string arg) override { ... }
};
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/E8HihV)

Comment: Hi there, great answer! Super got there first and got the accepted answer unfortunately, but that is precisely what I was after